# Adding a heading to output from pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to add a heading CIDGEN and NATION to my output in pl/sql script, but not able to figure out.

Below is my pl/sql script:

```
DECLARE
    v_concat VARCHAR2(2000);
    v_nation VARCHAR2(2000);
    err_msg  varchar2(300);
    v_header_printed BOOLEAN := FALSE;

BEGIN

v_nation := NULL;

  FOR ID in 1..p_nations.count
  LOOP
    v_nation := p_nations(ID);

        FOR rec IN (
        SELECT B.CIDGEN, B.NATION
        FROM COMPANY B
        JOIN NATION_LOOKUP C ON B.NATION = C.CODE
        WHERE B.CIDGEN IN (
            SELECT CIDGEN
            FROM RAN.OA_REQUEST_RESPONSE_STATUS
            WHERE RESPONSE_STATUS = 'FailedRequest'
            AND RESPONSE_UPDATE_STAMP >= TO_DATE(p_lastrundate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
        )
        AND B.NATION = v_nation
       ) LOOP
           IF NOT v_header_printed THEN
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CIDGEN' || '||' || 'NATION');
              v_header_printed := TRUE;
           END IF;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.CIDGEN || '||' || rec.NATION);
    END LOOP;
   END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception caught: ' || err_msg);
END;
/

exit
```

However I tried adding
           `IF NOT v_header_printed THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CIDGEN' || '||' || 'NATION'); v_header_printed := TRUE; END IF;`
in my block, but no able to print the heading CIDGEN     NATION in my output.

I am getting output as below:
`1054958001||AN 1678359002||AN 1568893001||AN`

I am expecting it to come as:
`CIDGEN||NATION 1054958001||AN 1678359002||AN 1568893001||AN`

Comment: Your code seems to do exactly what you want, at least once the two `p_*` variables are included. It does print the header line. (Demo [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/I06COFMh) using MT0's table setup.) Maybe test it again; or look at how you're running this - maybe via a script that is cutting off the first line of output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to check whether heading was printed? Why wouldn't you - instead - put it **out** of the loop?

```
FOR ID IN 1 .. p_nations.count LOOP

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('CIDGEN' || '||' || 'NATION');     --> here

  FOR rec IN (select ... FROM comapny ...) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(rec.CIDGEN || '||' || rec.NATION);
  END LOOP;

END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code to a single `SELECT` (and eliminate the nested loops):

```sql
DECLARE
  p_nation STRING_LIST := STRING_LIST('AA', 'BB', 'CC');
  p_lastrundate VARCHAR2(20) := '01-JAN-1970 00:00:00';
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CIDGEN' || '||' || 'NATION');
  FOR rec IN (
    SELECT B.CIDGEN,
           B.NATION
    FROM   COMPANY B
           INNER JOIN NATION_LOOKUP C
           ON B.NATION = C.CODE
           INNER JOIN TABLE(p_nation) n
           ON B.nation = n.COLUMN_VALUE
    WHERE  B.CIDGEN IN (
             SELECT CIDGEN
             FROM   RAN.OA_REQUEST_RESPONSE_STATUS
             WHERE  RESPONSE_STATUS = 'FailedRequest'
             AND    RESPONSE_UPDATE_STAMP >=
                      TO_DATE(p_lastrundate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
          )
  )
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.CIDGEN || '||' || rec.NATION);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE company (cidgen, nation) AS
SELECT 'Acme Corporation',     'AA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Octan',                'CC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Umbrella Corporation', 'BB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Wayne Enterprises',    'BB' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE nation_lookup (code) AS
SELECT 'AA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CC' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE RAN.OA_REQUEST_RESPONSE_STATUS (cidgen, response_status, response_update_stamp) AS
SELECT 'Acme Corporation',     'FailedRequest', SYSDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Octan',                'FailedRequest', SYSDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Umbrella Corporation', 'FailedRequest', SYSDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Wayne Enterprises',    'FailedRequest', SYSDATE FROM DUAL

CREATE TYPE string_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(200);
```

Outputs:

```
CIDGEN||NATION
Acme Corporation||AA
Octan||CC
Umbrella Corporation||BB
Wayne Enterprises||BB
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZrmpBPxa)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like below:

```
DECLARE
    v_concat VARCHAR2(2000);
    v_nation VARCHAR2(2000);
    err_msg  varchar2(300);
    v_header_printed BOOLEAN := FALSE;

BEGIN
    v_nation := NULL;

    FOR ID in 1..p_nations.count
    LOOP
        v_nation := p_nations(ID);

        FOR rec IN (
            SELECT B.CIDGEN, B.NATION
            FROM COMPANY B
            JOIN NATION_LOOKUP C ON B.NATION = C.CODE
            WHERE B.CIDGEN IN (
                SELECT CIDGEN
                FROM RAN.OA_REQUEST_RESPONSE_STATUS
                WHERE RESPONSE_STATUS = 'FailedRequest'
                AND RESPONSE_UPDATE_STAMP >= TO_DATE(p_lastrundate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
            )
            AND B.NATION = v_nation
        ) LOOP
            IF NOT v_header_printed THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CIDGEN' || '||' || 'NATION');
                v_header_printed := TRUE;
            END IF;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.CIDGEN || '||' || rec.NATION);
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception caught: ' || err_msg);
END;
/
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as the code in the question - all you've changed is the blank line and indentation for the `v_nation := NULL;` assignment. If you had intended to change something you lost that along the way; but you should also explain what you changed, and why.